# Webpart javascript does not work for array

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, jslint

I do not know Sharepoint scripts and my colleague does not know JavaScript.
He uses this script that he found on http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=228 to set the rows for a column called Progress1 to either show a red or green image;

```
// JS Link script to show good and bad in colors 
// Upload this file in _catalogs/masterpages as a JavaScript Display Template
(function () {
    var patientFieldCtx = {};

    // Define template variable
    patientFieldCtx.Templates = {};

    // Define your required fields and functions to call in each case.
    // In our case the field is Progress
    // Override Function is PatientProgressViewTemplate

    patientFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "Progress1": {
            "View": PatientProgressViewTemplate
        },

    };

    // Register the template override with SP2013
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(
    patientFieldCtx
    );

})();

// Override Progress Level field with color based on conditional value 
function PatientProgressViewTemplate(ctx) {
    var _progressValue = ctx.CurrentItem.Progress1;

     if (_progressValue == 'Good') //field value
     {
         //return "<font style='color:green'>" + _progressValue + "</font>";
         return "<div style='text-align: center;' ><img src='../../SiteAssets/Green_Light_Icon.png' height='16' width='16'/>";

     }

     if (_progressValue == 'Bad')
     {
         return "<div style='text-align: center;' ><img src='../../SiteAssets/Red_Light_Icon.png' height='16' width='16'/>";
     }
}
```

In the same view there is another column called Progress2, where the same script needs to apply.
So I suggested;

```
// JS Link script to show good and bad in colors 
// Upload this file in _catalogs/masterpages as a JavaScript Display Template
(function () {
    var patientFieldCtx = {};
    var columns = ["Progress1", "Progress2"];

    for (var index = 0; index < columns.length; index++) { 
        // Define template variable
        patientFieldCtx.Templates = {};

        // Define your required fields and functions to call in each case.
        // In our case the field is Progress
        // Override Function is PatientProgressViewTemplate

        patientFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
            columns[index]: {
                "View": PatientProgressViewTemplate
            },

        };

        // Register the template override with SP2013
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(patientFieldCtx);
    }

})();

// Override Progress Level field with color based on conditional value 
function PatientProgressViewTemplate(ctx) {

    var _progressValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];


     if (_progressValue == 'Good') //field value
     {
         //return "<font style='color:green'>" + _progressValue + "</font>";
         return "<div style='text-align: center;' ><img src='../../SiteAssets/Green_Light_Icon.png' height='16' width='16'/>";

     }

     if (_progressValue == 'Bad')
     {
         return "<div style='text-align: center;' ><img src='../../SiteAssets/Red_Light_Icon.png' height='16' width='16'/>";
     }
}
```

However this does not work. There are no clues as to why.
I have to admit although I have VS I am not using VS to test this. I suspect I will have to.

Comment: I suppose you talk about JSLink. JSLink is present on columns, view, etc, Where you register your script ? Anyway I think you can't do this: `columns[index]` but I'm not sure..

Comment: Yes this is about JSLint, I have just put the tag in the question. I do not know where the script gets registered.

Comment: I have update solution it should work look below=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set Fields in one part of code like this:

```
patientFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "Progress1" : {
            "View": PatientProgressViewTemplate
        },
        "Progress2" : {
            "View": PatientProgressViewTemplate
        }
    };
```

**For array try this solution:**

```
    var patientFieldCtx = {};
    var columns = ["Progress1", "Progress2"];
    patientFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    patientFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {};
    for (var index = 0; index < columns.length; index++) { 
            patientFieldCtx.Templates.Fields[columns[index]]= {"View": PatientProgressViewTemplate};
    }
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(patientFieldCtx);
```

Comment: The eval solution did not work, but your first answer did work. So thank you for that. Ideally I want the eval solution to work as there may be a number of fields that we want to apply this too. Maybe the difference is that for the eval to work it is within a loop and this causes the problem? Anyway, good to make some progress.